# How to check if two filenames exists in different folders

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

There are 3 folders. Need to check to see if a filename that exists in folder 1 already exists in folder 2. Move file from folder 1 to folder 3 if filename in folder 2 does not exist. If file name exists in folder 2, do nothing.

Tried this script. But I now see that it checks for any .pdf files in the second folder so it just moves all the files from the 1st folder to the 3rd folder if it sees any .pdfs in the 2nd folder. I think it needs to check if the names are the exact same but not sure how to proceed.

```
@echo off 
title test
ping localhost -n 2 > nul
cd "C:\test"

@echo off &setlocal
set "firstFolder=C:\test\firstsource"
set "destination=C:\test\destination"
set "secondfolder=C:\test\secondsource"
set suffix=.pdf

for %%i in ("%firstfolder%\*%suffix%") do (
    IF NOT EXIST "%secondfolder%%%~i%suffix%" (
        move /y "%%~i" "%destination%"
        echo "moving 1 file"
    ) ELSE (
    ECHO "file exists"
    )
)
pause
endlocal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[untested]

```
IF NOT EXIST "%secondfolder%\%%~nxi" (
```

Selecting the **n**ame and e**x**tension of the filename to `%secondfolder%`

See `for /?` from the prompt for documentation

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension of Magoo's existing and correct answer, to remove some unnecessary stuff.

I think you may just need to use one of the modifiers mentioned in the help information when <kbd>ENTER</kbd>ing `for /?` in a Command Prompt window, *in this case `%%~nx` (for name and extension)*.

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Title test

Set "FirstDirectory=C:\test\firstsource"
Set "SecondDirectory=C:\test\secondsource"
Set "DestinationDirectory=C:\test\destination"
Set "Extension=.pdf"

For %%G In ("%FirstDirectory%\*%Extension%") Do If Not Exist "%SecondDirectory%\%%~nxG" (
    Echo Moving 1 file.
    Move /Y "%%~G" "%DestinationDirectory%"
) Else Echo File exists.

Pause
EndLocal
```